# Ruby: How do I return a MySQL query up an SSH tunnel?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ssh

//update: when feeding mysql passwords, -ppassword works.  -p password does -not- work.  Problem solved.//

We have hundreds of databases on our work servers, and I'd like to write a ruby script that automates the process of creating duplicate versions of them on my local machine for development purposes.

I've been trying to use net-ssh to create the tunnel, but (host, user, pass, etc. are censored for obvious reasons):

```
require 'net/ssh'

HOST = 'xxx'
USER = 'yyy'
PASS = 'ppp'

Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|
    puts "inside ssh tunnel"
    puts ssh.exec!('ruby -v')
    puts ssh.exec!('mysql -u zzz -p pswrd -h c3 will_il_raw -e "select * from deeds limit 1"')
end
```

results in the output:

```
inside ssh tunnel
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
```

followed by an indefinite hang.  Interestingly, if I ssh into the same computer via the console, 'ruby -v' returns 1.9.3.  If I enter that mysql query there, it successfully returns one line of the named table.

I assume the solution has something to do with port forwarding, but here my limited knowledge begins to fail me utterly.

The machine running the mysql server is not the same machine as I am accessing it from, which is not, in turn, the machine I am actually sitting at.  I need to connect the dots and apparently have no idea how to go about this properly.

Any protips would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only tip that I have is that your problem isn't port-forwarding.

Comment: Nevermind.  Apparently the problem was syntax.  I had a space between the -p and the password in the script -_-

$%^&.  Well.  Wish I had that five hours back.

Comment: Maybe delete your question then, if you don't think it will be relevant to other users?

Comment: @MaxwellEvans you should post that as an answer

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** do it this way. Running SQL from the command line is reckless. It's also going to be hell to make use of the results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a ssh tunnel in ruby and then connect to mysql server on the remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103809/how-to-create-a-ssh-tunnel-in-ruby-and-then-connect-to-mysql-server-on-the-remot)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL syntax, when feeding a password using -p[password], there is no space between -p and the password.

Because the script's version of the syntax had a space, the result of the query was a prompt requesting the password, which caused the hang on the far end of the SSH tunnel.