# convert mysql result to array or hash

Tags: mysql, ruby, sqldatatypes

SQL query:-

```
Class Test
def self.execute_mysql(host, database, query)
    Net::SSH.start('test.com', user, forward_agent: true) do |ssh|
      ssh.exec!("mysql -ppassword -utestuser -h #{host} #{database} -A --execute '#{query}'")
end
end
```

Command to run:-

```
result = Test.execute_mysql('app', 'sample', 'select * from foo')
```

result string:-

```
id  name address age
1   ram US 25
2   sam US 30
3   jack India 32
.
.
.
.
100 Peterson US 27
```

result variable returns as string class. Suppose it returns 100 records.How can i loop through each record ?

Comment: Please post the `result` string. It'll help explain what you are starting from.

Comment: @roob I have updated result string. Kindly look at it.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
 > result
 => "id  name address age\n1   ram US 25\n2   sam US 30\n3   jack India 32"
 > result.split(" ").each_slice(4){|e| print e }
 => ["id", "name", "address", "age"]["1", "ram", "US", "25"]["2", "sam", "US", "30"]["3", "jack", "India", "32"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on a lot of things, and you carefully need to put a lot of checks to make it robust.

I'll however post a simple answer based on some assumptions to get you started on.

```
res =  "id  name address age
        1   ram US 25
        2   sam US 30
        3   jack India 32"

arr = []
res.each_line {|line| arr << line.split(" ")}
arr
# => [["id", "name", "address", "age"], ["1", "ram", "US", "25"], ["2", "sam", "US", "30"], ["3", "jack", "India", "32"]]
```

Now you can easily iterate over the arrays to access particular attribute.

Comment: Is there any way to convert result into mysql object

Comment: the way you are doing it (i.e. with ssh) its not possible as per my knowledge. However you may want to try `mysql2` gem. Here for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103809/how-to-create-a-ssh-tunnel-in-ruby-and-then-connect-to-mysql-server-on-the-remot/#answer-9912538