# Migrating Data from Remote MySQL server to Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

This is a follow up question to "[How to create a ssh tunnel in ruby and then connect to mysql server on the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103809/how-to-create-a-ssh-tunnel-in-ruby-and-then-connect-to-mysql-server-on-the-remot)" from 5 years ago.

I'm trying to create an SSH tunnel in Ruby and then connect to a remote MySQL database. I'm doing this because I need to move some legacy data from an older version of my app, so I don't need ActiveRecord, migrations, etc.

I'm using the [NetSSHGateway gem](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh-gateway) and the [MySQL2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).

Here's my Ruby code (run in rails console):

```
gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('old_remote_server.com','server_username')
port = gateway.open('127.0.0.1', 3306, 3307)
client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  host: "127.0.0.1", 
  username: 'database_username', 
  password: 'database_password', 
  database: 'database_name', 
  port: port
)
```

After the last line, the console hangs for about 2 minutes, and then gives me the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I am able to SSH into the remote server, and execute MySQL commands that way, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the Sequel ORM. Besides being a useful ORM it has the ability to easily migrate data from one DBM to another. See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/bin_sequel_rdoc.html#label-Copy+Databases

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, this isn't likely the best way to migrate data, for a few reasons.

In the end, I simply dumped my legacy MySQL database, moved it to my new app's environment, and used the [MySQL2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) to build rake tasks to translate and move the data into my new app.